# Photoelectric effect on charged plate

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, photoelectric-effect, metals, ionization-energy

As far as I know, to observe the photoelectric effect, one has to expose a metal surface to high-energy radiation. But what happens if the surface has a surplus of electrons? What is the energy needed to knock of those? Would a lower frequency be sufficient to produce the same effect?

Comment: Visible light with an energy of approx. 1eV is not considered high energy radiation. If you add enough excess electrons, there are no photons necessary at all, that's called field emission.

Comment: Does radiation lower the threshold potential for field emission? I.e. can radiation below the material's work function combined with fewer excess electrons needed for field emission still lead to electron emission?

Comment: Field emission is spontaneous, it doesn't need radiation, but you can, of course, have an enhancement. Think about a hot cathode, usually implemented as a filament. By raising the thermal energy of the electrons, we are increasing their emission probability and we usually apply an electric field to overcome the potential barrier (work function) at the metal-vacuum surface.

Comment: Could both high temperature and an electric field also be used to manipulate the threshold wavelength for the photoelectric effect?

Comment: Yes, but you don't gain anything from that for photo-detection, both effects will raise the noise more than they will help with the increase of quantum efficiency for the conversion of photons into photo-electrons, which in a modern device is very efficient.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what gain in overall electron yield could be expected from a modest temperature increase of, say a few dozen degrees C?

Comment: Very small. 1eV (the energy of a visible photon) is equal to almost 12000K in temperature. A few degrees won't make any difference. To overcome the work function one has to heat the cathodes till they glow red hot. If you need close to 100% quantum efficiency, use a photodiode and the inner photo-effect. If you need fast timing resolution and single photon detection, but can live with 20% quantum efficiency, use photomultiplier tubes. If you want to see real life performance, download the Hamamatsu photomultiplier handbook. You will see that the dark current goes up with T, which is bad.

Comment: @CuriousOne You should probably convert those comments into an actual answer...

Answer (score 1):

When light falls on the photoelectric surface, photoelectric radiations are emitted, when the energy is more than the work function i.e when more electrons are made to fall on the photoelectric surface,it will go beyond the work function and electrons will be emitted normally.

No,there will be not the same effect because, $f=\frac1\lambda$,where wavelength is inversely proportional to the frequency.